# Is there a limit on the size and number of OIDC 1.0 Claims?

Tags: openid-connect

I see OIDC 1.0 claims as a nice mechanism to populate authorization information at the time of authentication. Is there a wise limit on the amount of information to stuff in a JWT, i.e. both number of entries and size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you may reach some browser or infrastructure limits.

Some implementations store token in the cookie, so you may reach single cookie size limit (usually 4k bytes per single cookie). Workaround is to divide token into smaller chunks and those chunks will be stored in the cookies.

Token is part of request headers usually and header buffers are also limited by used infrastructure (e.g. nginx has defailt 8k bytes limit). Of course you can adjust those configurations only if you manage those devices.

I would say that there is typical 8k bytes technical limit. You can do more, but there is higher chance of users problems then.

Answer (score 1):

It is also worth thinking about what is best in terms of privacy and extensibility.

An alternative option is to have tokens just identify the caller and then use a claims caching solution server side.
https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/

Quite a few systems work like this - eg AWS API Gateway.

Comment: Would you say the authorization code flow in OIDC is an example of this, i.e. where claims are only available on the server via an accessToken HTTP RPC?

Comment: There are similarities - especially when the web UI receives cookies from a back end and the cookie contains a jwt. In cases where the UI actually receives a jwt it is generally best to keep it small and confidential - as above.